# How to use a Access Database in Visual Studio

Tags: c, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I have created a database with MS Access (only the fields of a table). Now I am in Visual Studio Express 2013 and I would like to insert some values in the database.
I read from

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

that you should add this line of code

```
#import <C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE12\\ACEDAO.dll> rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )
```

but when I insert this line in my project I get the red line and it says

```
"Error: Cannot open source file <directory_of_project>\ACEDAO.tlh"
```

Could you please help me? Thanks!
PS: I have to use C

Comment: do you have the dll acedao in the path specified from the import?

Comment: Yeah I do.. I manage to do it by changing the compiler from C to C++...